# Prestashop | Remove transplant restrictions

Tags: hook, prestashop, transplant

So, there's a problem - I need to transplant "Categories Block" module to "displayTopColumn" hook (yep, designer put categories list near (on?) slider). But, by default, there is no possibilities to do this. I don't like that awful Prestashop restrictions, so maybe there is solution for this problem - remove those restrictions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing those restrictions would not resolve anything for a simple reason: if you could hook the module `blockcategories` to `displayTopColumn`, this module would not know what to display in this hook because there is no `hookDisplayTopColumn()` function in it.

However, you can modify the module, and add a function to manage this hook.

To do so, open the file `blockcategories.php` and add the following:

```
public function hookDisplayTopColumn($params)
{
    // Your code
}
```

If you want to display here the same content as in the `hookLeftColumn` hook, you can simply do this:

```
public function hookDisplayTopColumn($params)
{
    return $this->hookLeftColumn($params);
}
```

You can also create your own function and template by copying, pasting and modifying the code you can find in the function `hookLeftColumn()` or in the function `hookFooter()`.